# Setting up traffic for GRE Tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I want to set up clients that are behind NAT with a public IP but allow them to have one or more public IP's on their device. The idea is to have a Linux box with either 1 or two network cards. Let's take two for simplicity.

```
Router1 Loop back interface: 100.100.100.1/30
Router1 if1 - 100.100.100.5/30
Router1 static route: 172.16.50.0/24 via 100.100.100.6
Router1 static route: 172.16.50.0/24 via 100.100.100.6

VPN_Server1: 100.100.100.6/30
```

Linux_box1 with two interfaces:

```
eth0: DHCP from router (IP will most likely be 192.168.1.10/24 with default GW of 192.168.1.1)
eth1: 100.100.100.129/25
PPTP/L2TP or some other sort of protocol that will connect to the VPN server with.
```

The VPN servers IP will say be 172.16.50.1 and the Linux box will have 172.16.50.2.

I will then set up a GRE tunnel between 172.16.50.1 and 100.100.100.1.

The overall goal that I am trying to do is give clients a device that will be as if they are with me in the data center. They will connect a server to Linux_box1 as a router and go out to the internet. There is one other scenario where the Linux box will have a public IP however it won't be static from the ISP so it will still need the tunnel. However in this case there is no point in sending back the traffic via the tunnel. We would simply send it out to the internet.